# Function within a function is not defined?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Hello I have code that is written as follows. It is written in ipython, so each function is written in a cell.

```
**Cell 1:**
def linear_activation_forward(A_prev, W, b, activation):
    *some code*
    return A, cache

**Cell 2:**
def L_model_forward(X, parameters):
    *some code*
    AL, cache = linear_activation_forward(A, 
                                             parameters["W" + str(L)], 
                                             parameters["b" + str(L)], 
                                             activation='sigmoid')
    *some code*
    return AL, caches

**Cell 3:**
def L_layer_model(X, Y, layers_dims, learning_rate = 0.0075, num_iterations = 3000, print_cost=False):
    *some code*
     AL, caches = L_model_forward(X, parameters)
    *some code*
    return parameters

**cell4**
parameters = L_layer_model(train_x, train_set_y_orig, layer_dims, learning_rate = 0.0075, num_iterations = 3000, print_cost = True)
```

If I run Cell 1 I have no error
If I run Cell 2 I have no error
If I run Cell 3 I have no error
If I run Cell 4 then I have that my function of Cell 1 is not defined

NameError: name 'linear_activation_forward' is not defined

Does anybody have any clue? Tnx

Comment: it shouldn't be a problem. debug your functions step by step. for example, just call your first function with random value as input argumans in second cell and see how it works, then call it into another functions

Comment: Hello, not sure how to debug, If I would do it as proposed (see first comment), I'll guess everything should be fine till I run the fourth cell and then I will again have the error function bla bla is not defined... no? Is there no clue at first site what could be possible go wrong, but anyway I will try to debug and see what is the outcome.